# Clean characterization of the matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Does anyone have a clean characterization of the matrix of a linear transformation? I would like one that is concise and clean. This is what I have, although I am not sure if it is correct:

**Matrix of the transformation T with respect to B,C:**

The matrix M such that $T(x)=Mx$ $\forall x$ in the domain and such that the columns of M are the coordinate vectors of the image of the transformation with respect to **C**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the statement $T(x) = Mx$ doesn't make sense, since the former is an element of a general vector space and the latter is a vector in $R^m.$

To be more precise, you could say that if $T:V \rightarrow W$ is a linear map between spaces of dimension $n,m$ respectively, then $M$ is the unique $m \times n$ matrix such that $[T(x)]_C = M[x]_B$ for every $x \in V$, where $[ \cdot ]_B$ is the coordinate isomorphism in the basis $B.$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $b_1,..,b_n$ is a basis for the domain and $c_1,...c_m$ is a basis for the range.

Then any element of the domain can be specified (uniquely, by assumption) by $\sum_k x_k b_k$, and similarly, any element of the range can be specified by $\sum_k y_k c_k$.

Since $T$ is linear, we need only specify $T$ on a basis, in this case we need $ Tb_1,...,T b_m$. Since each of these is in the range, each of the $Tb_k$ can be specified in terms of the $c_j$. The matrix $M$ is what specifies how the $Tb_k$ are specified in terms of the $c_j$.

In particular, let $T b_i = \sum_k [M]_{ki} c_k$ (note the indices on $M$ are $ki$, not $ik$).

Then if $v = \sum_i x_i b_i$, we have $Tv = \sum_i x_i T b_i = \sum_i x_i \sum_k [M]_{ki} c_k = \sum_k (\sum_i [M]_{ki} x_i) c_k = \sum_k [Mx]_k c_k$.

That is, if a point $v$ in the domain has coordinates $(x_1,...,x_n)^T$ (with respect to $b_1,...,b_n$, of course), then the point $Tv$ has coordinates $([Mx]_1,...,[Mx]_m)^T = Mx$.